# Accessing an html file from cache memory

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python that does following things:
1) gets an html file from internet.
2) extracts its urls.
3) compare these urls with a search key and opens the correct webpage that user wants to open.
I am using following code:

```
def open_page(name):

    try:
        links = lxml.html.parse('http://www.w3schools.com/html/').xpath("//a/@href")
        for url in links:
            if re.search(name, url):
                self.get_webpage.open('http://www.w3schools.com/html/'+url)
                break
    except IndexError as e:
        pass`
```

I have to call this method many times in my module which is making the process of opening webpage very slow. I tried to check the execution time of each line of this method and came to know that lxml.html.parse() is consuming most of the time. Also if I try to use some html file which is stored in local system, this method works speedily. Is there any way that we can get the html file of this webpage http://www.w3schools.com/html/ from cache after first time?
p.s. I do not want to save this html file permanently in my local system, because in that case I can miss the updates/changes on this html file.

Comment: If you're not saving the file on disk, then where would the cache be? Is the problem that you're calling this function repeatedly even though nothing will have changed most of the time?

Comment: Ok I am sorry I put question in a wrong way. can you tell me how I can use the cashed file instead of using http://www.w3schools.com/html/ inside lxml.html.parse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you do want to cache the page, but you also want to check that nothing has changed since you last downloaded it.

The [If-Modified-Since](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.25) HTTP header is your friend in this endeavor. When making an HTTP GET request, you can provide that header field with the time you last downloaded the page. If the page has not changed on the server since that time, the server will return a [304 Not Modified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.5) status code and will not send the page content, saving you the trouble of downloading it again.

Here's how you might go about doing this in Python 2:

```
import contextlib
import datetime
import urllib2

with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(
        "http://www.w3schools.com/html/",
        headers={"If-Modified-Since": last_access_time}))) as u:
    if u.getcode() != 304:
        cached_html = lxml.html.parse(u)
        last_access_time = datetime.datetime.now()
html = cached_html
```

`last_access_time` and `cached_html` are likely stored on disk.

Comment: Good answer.  But note that `last_access_time`, when sent as the value of `If-modified-since`, must be in RFC2616 format.  E.g., "Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT".  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25

Answer (score 0):

You could store the htmls  together with a time stamp, and only download the html if the html is too old.